# Generic messages in message-based architecture

Tags: swift, generics, elm

I am experimenting with message-based architecture in Swift. I am trying to do something similar to the Elm Architecture, for example. This is how my code looks:

```
enum SideEffect<Message> {

    case sendRequest((String) -> Message)
}

protocol Component {

    associatedtype Message

    mutating func send(msg: Message) -> [SideEffect<Message>]
}

struct State: Component {

    var something: String?

    enum Message {

        case downloadSomething
        case receiveResponse(String)
    }

    mutating func send(msg: Message) -> [SideEffect<Message>] {
        switch msg {
            case .downloadSomething:
                return [.sendRequest(Message.receiveResponse)]
            case .receiveResponse(let response):
                something = response
                return []
        }
    }
}
```

So the state is modelled by `State` and you can change it by sending `Message`s. If there are any side effects to compute, they are returned as a `SideEffect` message and will be taken care of by someone else. Each `SideEffect` message takes a “callback” argument, a `Message` to send when the side effect is finished. This works great.

Now, what if I want to have a generic side effect message? I would like to have something like this:

```
struct Request<ReturnType> { … }
```

And have a related side effect to load the request and return a value of type `ReturnType`:

```
enum SideEffect<Message> {
    case sendRequest(Request<T>, (T) -> Message)
}
```

But this (obviously) doesn’t compile, as the `case` would have to be generic over `T`. I can’t make the whole `SideEffect` generic over `T`, since there’s other side effects that have nothing to do with `T`.

Can I somehow create a `SideEffect` message with a `Request<T>` that would later dispatch a `Message` with `T`? (I think I want something like [this feature discussed on swift-evolution](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20170424/036095.html).)

Comment: How about we make a protocol `Returnable` and make the `ReturnType` conform to this protocol? Then we can also extend other types, like `String`, to conform to this protocol as well.

Comment: You'll want to type erase `T`, usually this can be done with closures (for example you make a closure that performs the request and then passes the result to your function that then yields a message, thus hiding the type of `T` from the outside world). I'm not at all familiar with the Elm Architecture and therefore am not sure how you're expecting `Request` to be implemented, but would [something like this](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59e15aad6cbea87f72c470cc) be viable?

Comment: Hamish to the rescue again! I think that’s exactly what I needed. I was beating around type erasure, but apparently I didn’t get quite used to the concept so I didn’t come up with the solution. Thank you very much! I have flagged the question to have your comment converted to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to type erase `T` – usually this can be done with closures, as they can reference context from the site at which they're created, without exposing that context to the outside world.

For example, with a mock `Request<T>` (assuming it's an async operation):

```
struct Request<T> {

    var mock: T

    func doRequest(_ completion: @escaping (T) -> Void) {
        // ...
        completion(mock)
    }
}
```

We can build a `RequestSideEffect<Message>` that holds a closure that takes a given `(Message) -> Void` callback, and then performs a request on a captured `Request<T>` instance, forwarding the result through a `(T) -> Message`, the result of which can then be passed back to the callback (thus keeping the type variable `T` 'contained' in the closure):

```
struct RequestSideEffect<Message> {

    private let _doRequest: (@escaping (Message) -> Void) -> Void

    init<T>(request: Request<T>, nextMessage: @escaping (T) -> Message) {
        self._doRequest = { callback in
            request.doRequest {
                callback(nextMessage($0))
            }
        }
    }

    func doRequest(_ completion: @escaping (Message) -> Void) {
        _doRequest(completion)
    }
}
```

Now your `SideEffect<Message>` can look like this:

```
enum SideEffect<Message> {
    case sendRequest(RequestSideEffect<Message>)
}
```

And you can implement `State` like this:

```
protocol Component {
    associatedtype Message
    mutating func send(msg: Message) -> [SideEffect<Message>]
}

struct State: Component {

    var something: String

    enum Message {
        case downloadSomething
        case receiveResponse(String)
    }

    mutating func send(msg: Message) -> [SideEffect<Message>] {
        switch msg {
        case .downloadSomething:
            let sideEffect = RequestSideEffect(
                request: Request(mock: "foo"), nextMessage: Message.receiveResponse
            )
            return [.sendRequest(sideEffect)]
        case .receiveResponse(let response):
            something = response
            return []
        }
    }
}

var s = State(something: "hello")
let sideEffects = s.send(msg: .downloadSomething)

for case .sendRequest(let sideEffect) in sideEffects {
    sideEffect.doRequest {
        _ = s.send(msg: $0) // no side effects expected
        print(s) // State(something: "foo")
    }
}
```